# Action Hook: item.create not passing data

Tags: directus

I have three action hooks on my 'subscribers' collection in my application:

```
'item.update.subscribers' => function (array $data) {}
'item.delete.subscribers' => function (array $data) {}
'item.create.subscribers' => function (array $data) {}
```

and the following filter hook:

```
'item.create.subscribers:before' => function (\Directus\Hook\Payload $payload) {}
```

All hooks except for action `item.create.subscribers` hook work as expected. This is the error I'm getting in the browser console:

[image]

if I change the function arg to `function ($data)`, `$data` is `null`.

Comment: May I have the error logs? It will be a great help to check the culprit for 500 error code. You can find if from the logs directory.

Comment: @BinalGajjar there's nothing in the logs directory

Comment: @JRedford — did you check all the different logs? Directus, apache, php, mysql, etc?

Answer (score 0):

@JRedford - It seems like; there is an issue for storing the data and it's not an issue of hooks.

Can you please confirm once that the data stored successfully in DB?

If yes - then check the logs as @RANGER suggested.